# OSMDroid crashes when zooming out

Tags: android, osmdroid

I´ve added a OSMDroid map in my app and it works fine, but if I zoom out, it crashes.

I add one Item while loading the Map at the user´s current position, and load 10 more in an AsyncTask after loading the map.

---

**UPDATE: Working Solution**

In my old Code below, I added one "base"-Item to the map at the user´s location and created an `ItemizedItemOverlay` for the map. Then I loaded more OverlayItems and added them to the list, but they didn´t appear on the map.

Now I create the `ItemizedItemOverlay` after the AsyncTask has finished loading all the Items, now the Items are all visible, `OnItemSingleTapUp` is working as intended, Double-Tap on the map works as well and there are no more crashes. I still don´t really know what caused the crashes, but it works like this.

---

**Possible problem:**
The List of OverlayItems is initialized with zero objects (obviously), but after I add one OverlayItem, it contains 1 OverlayItem + 11 more null-Objects (or null-Refernces? null-Items? what´s the correct term?) 
**EDIT:** didnt cause the problems, still strange.

**EDIT:** It seems as I only get a crash when adding more Items.

Here´s my full code and Logcat:

```
mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
mapController = this.mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(25);
GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(DataManager.glat, DataManager.glon);
mapController.setCenter(center);
mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100,
        this);

items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(); // items now null
items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", center));
// items now contains 1 OverlayItem and 11 null-items

this.mLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index,
                    final OverlayItem item) {

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("newShopName", item.mTitle);
                intent.putExtra("newShopAdd", item.mDescription);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish(); 

                return true; 
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index,
                    final OverlayItem item) {

                toast = Toast.makeText(ShopChooseActivity.this, item.mTitle + ", " + item.mDescription, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                return false;
            }
        }, mResourceProxy);

this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Here I call the AsyncTask:

```
loadMap = new LoadChooseShop(ShopChooseActivity.this, items).execute();
```

And here I "refresh" the map:

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(int returncode) {
        try {
            items = loadMap.get();

            if(items != null)
            mapView.invalidate();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_connectionfailure , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        }
    }
```

And the XML:

```
 <org.osmdroid.views.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/mapview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

**BIG EDIT:** Most of my problems are now resolved, it still crashes.

It always crashes when I double-tap on the map, but not only then.
If I add `clickable=true` to XML, it doesnt crash anymore, but I can´t move the map.

The Logcat:

```
07-15 14:41:16.339: E/InputEventReceiver(17302): Exception dispatching input event.
07-15 14:41:16.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay.getItem(ItemizedOverlay.java:157)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.activateSelectedItems(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:170)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.onSingleTapUp(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:117)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayManager.onSingleTapUp(OverlayManager.java:291)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.MapView$MapViewGestureDetectorListener.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:1539)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:1344)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchTouchEvent(MapView.java:904)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-15 14:41:16.404: E/MessageQueue-JNI(17302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 14:41:21.914: D/AndroidRuntime(17302): Shutting down VM
07-15 14:41:21.914: W/dalvikvm(17302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417cc2a0)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay.getItem(ItemizedOverlay.java:157)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.activateSelectedItems(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:170)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.onSingleTapUp(ItemizedIconOverlay.java:117)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayManager.onSingleTapUp(OverlayManager.java:291)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView$MapViewGestureDetectorListener.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:1539)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:1344)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchTouchEvent(MapView.java:904)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-15 14:41:21.984: E/AndroidRuntime(17302):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update:**
If I don´t add more Items (don´t call AsyncTask), tapping on the Item works and delivers the expected result - but if I add more Items, it crashes on Tap. (on Tap of the same Item, the others aren´t even visible)

Comment: if(gps!=null && gps.canGetLocation()){
  //more safety code. avoids NPE
}

Comment: tried, but didnt work - like I said, gps is always set

Comment: can you post what's there in gps.canGetLocation()?

Comment: I can see some issue. "This method sets canGetLocation (Boolean ofc) and gets called in the constructor"

is it Boolean or boolean? If it's Boolean, there will be 100% chance that it's not initialized properly i.e. Null by default unlike boolean which will be either true or false only

Comment: this is the declaration: `boolean canGetLocation = false;`

Comment: you said  This method sets canGetLocation (Boolean ofc) 

Are you sure,you are not using/passing Boolean anywhere in code?

if not, it's bit hard to check what's the issue without complete code.

Comment: Just checked, whole class does not contain `Boolean`

Comment: just rebuild the app once and retest and keep logger before your if condition and after if condition and post the stacktrace again. Just make sure code is properly synchronized with target app

Comment: Added full method for updateGPS, might have found the problem - please see my edit

Comment: When you get an exception that you want help with, you really need to post the full exception including the stack trace.

Comment: How do I get the stacktrace without beeing able to catch the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your last edit you posted the full stacktrace - thank you, that is what we need. I would ignore the "Error downloading tile" since that isn't what is crashing your app. The crash is happening in the "IndexOutOfBoundsException". Your question is starting to spiral out of control with too much information - let's simplify it down and isolate the problem. What are you doing when the crash happens - you say in your question that it happens when you double-tap but the exception is related to the ItemizedIconOverlay and the onSingleTapUp. Some things to try:

1. Does it crash if you don't use the ItemizedIconOverlay?
2. Does it crash if you don't add any items to the ItemizedIconOverlay.
3. Looking at the ItemizedItemOverlay, what if you moved all the code in onSingleTapUp() to onSingleTapConfirmed(). That is really where it belongs. If you don't want to rebuild osmdroid from source, then you should be able to extend ItemizedIconOverlay and override both methods - return false in `onSingleTapUp()` and put all the old code from that method in `onSingleTapConfirmed`. I just added a ticket for that [Issue 450](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=450).
4. You say it crashes when you double-tap to zoom in, what about when you just tap on an item? Does it crash then? Make sure you aren't adding new items when you zoom in.

So the ItemizedOverlay works by calling `size()` and then it calls `getMarker(index)` for each item. For some reason your ItemizedOverlay thinks it has 2 items when it only has one. Maybe if you set some breakpoints, particularly in `addItem()` or `addItems()` and `size()`. Maybe that, along with the answers to the above, will provide some clues!

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I tested a bit, and it really seems to crash when I tap the (only visible) Item - In `OnItemSingleTapUp` all the code was executed successfully until `finish()`, after that he crashed, don´t know where yet though. But after the first run (debug) it didnt even reach the (same) checkpoints, as soon as I tap on the Item, I get a `Source not found` error, even though I haven´t changed anything... I´ll post an update as soon as I have more data

Comment: Updated question, it really seems to be the OnTap, but only if I add more Items. "For some reason your ItemizedOverlay thinks it has 2 items when it only has one." Yes, I already noticed this, the `items`-list actually has 12 Items, one "real" one and 11 nulls - see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653292/adding-overlay-items-to-osmdroid-map-in-asynctask)

Answer (score 3):

You can try overriding

- onSingleTapUp
- onSingleTapConfirmed

This worked for me..

```
@Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView){

   return true;
  }
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
{
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second LogCat's just telling you that [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) is not configured properly.

Incidentally, you've not posted your **full** code. If this were your complete source, it wouldn't pass the compile phase, as it's not syntactically correct.

Comment: This is all my code I have for OSMDroid, what do you mean is wrong?

Comment: Well, for one, it's missing the class declaration.

Comment: There´s a lot more in this activity, but it´s completely unrelated to this piece of code, so I only posted the code that matters

Comment: Let us determine what code is related and what isn't, post as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check who's modifying the "MainActivity". that's all I can say. 
If you are using Eclipse, keep a watch on that variable and you can see what's happening